# What is the use of parenthesis followed by row_number( ) ,rank( ) , dense_rank ( ) in SQL?

Tags: sql, function, window, rank, dense-rank

What is the use of parenthesis followed by row_number( ) ,rank( ) , dense_rank ( ) in SQL ?

Comment: Because they are functions and the basic function structure takes parameters which are supplied within parentheses

Comment: A function with zero parameters take the form `function()`.